# How to create a responsive three-column layout with grid and span the third column over two rows on specific breakpoints?

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, media-queries

I have a three-column layout using CSS Grid with `minmax()` to make it responsive.

[image]

In some breakpoints when the viewport is a certain width, the third column is pushed down to the next row

[image]

so i want to change this layout and make the third column span two rows when the breakpoint occurs.

[image]

I have tried using a media query to achieve this
and i had to manually determine the breakpoint range by using the dev tool.
When I changed the `minmax()` value, the breakpoint range also changed, breaking the layout again.

```html
 <div class="features ">
            <div class="f-card">
                    ....
            </div>
            <div class="f-card">
                    ....
            </div>
            <div class="f-card span">
                    ....
            </div>
        </div>
```

```css
.features {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(270px, 1fr));
    gap: var(--main-gap);
}

@media screen and (min-width:737px) and (max-width: 1102px)  {
    .f-card.span{
        grid-column: span 2;
    }
}
```

This works, but the issue is that I don't know the exact breakpoint range, and when I change the `minmax()` value, the breakpoint range also changes, breaking the layout.

Comment: How and when are you changing the breakpoint range? What determinesthat? Is there some JavaScript involved?

Comment: no, no javascript is used here, the minmax() function determines the breakpoint range it will wrap the column when the width of the column is less than 270px in this example, so i can't know when the breakpoint happens i just use dev tool and try to find the range when the third column wrap in the next row and use my media query, but when i change the value of the minmax() form 270px to 300px the breakpoint range its change automatically this how grid work with minmax()

Comment: Is there some reason not to use JavaScript?

Comment: no , i don't try to use js because I still learning CSS and practicing, but I will accept any solution for this problem even with js.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to base your grid on 12 cols, easier if you want later to add different layouts.

You have 3 states for your column:

- full width if small screen -> 1 col
- half on medium screen -> 2 cols
- 1/3 on large screen -> 3 cols

First define col as full (12 cols)
At medium break, 2 states possible: half or full
At large break, 1/3

*colors at end css only to visualize

```css
.features {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  gap: 10px;
}

.c1 {
  grid-column: auto / span 12;
}

@media screen and (min-width:560px) {}

@media screen and (min-width:737px) {
  .c1-2-md {
    grid-column: auto / span 6;
  }
  .c1-md {
    grid-column: auto / span 12;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1102px) {
  .c1-3-lg {
    grid-column: auto / span 4;
  }
}

.features>div:first-child {
  background-color: #0a79b3;
}

.features>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

.features>div:last-child {
  background-color: #7D572B;
}
```

```html
<div class="features ">
  <div class="f-card c1 c1-2-md c1-3-lg">
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="f-card c1 c1-2-md c1-3-lg">
    ....
  </div>
  <div class="f-card c1 c1-md c1-3-lg">
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```